# Show only one hidden row (Visual Page Builder accordion)

Tags: jquery, wordpress, accordion, visual-composer

I use Visual Page Builder (former Visual Composer) accordion element to show full width hidden rows below.
So in first row I have 3 accordions, clicking on each one opens a hidden row.
I added this code to functions.php

Can you please help - what code should I add to have only one hidden row opened on all this page?

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() { ?>

<script>

    ( function( $ ) {

        'use strict';

        $( document ).ready( function() {

            var $trigger = $( '.open-hiddenrow1' );
            var $hiddenRow = $( '.hiddenrow1' );
            
            if ( $hiddenRow.length ) {
                $trigger.click( function() {
                    $hiddenRow.toggle();
                    return false;
                } );
            }

        } );
        $( document ).ready( function() {
    
            var $trigger = $( '.open-hiddenrow2' );
            var $hiddenRow = $( '.hiddenrow2' );
            
            if ( $hiddenRow.length ) {
                $trigger.click( function() {
                    $hiddenRow.toggle();
                    return false;
                } );
            }

        } );
        $( document ).ready( function() {
    
            var $trigger = $( '.hiddenrow3' );
            var $hiddenRow = $( '.hiddenrow3' );
            
            if ( $hiddenRow.length ) {
                $trigger.click( function() {
                    $hiddenRow.toggle();
                    return false;
                } );
            }

        } );
    } ( jQuery ) );

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

This helped: I added class `.mainpageclass` to every accordion and `.mainpagehidrow` to hidden row, then this code:

```
  $(function () {
 $(".mainpageclass").click(function (e) {
  e.preventDefault();
  $(".mainpagehidrow").not($(this).toggleClass('open').next('.mainpagehidrow').fadeToggle("slow")).fadeOut('fast');
 });
```